How can I use another HDD for some directories?
For example, now I have two directories /home/anton/test1 and /home/anton/test2 with files in them, they are stored on the main SSD.
I'd like to use another HDD's partition (data partition on /dev/sda1 disk) for these directories. What is the right way to achieve this?


Does this answer your question? Move home folder to second drive

Move the folders to the new sda1 partition. Have fstab mount the partition where you want it, then mount --bind the folders on the sda1 partition to the locations in your home tree that you want them to be at. See man mount.

An alternative is to add an entry in fstab, mount partition and link folders from that drive. I mount all folders in /home, but you can select to only have a few. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk  If ext4 or other Linux format you also have to give yourself ownership & permissions.

So now that you have a directory at /media/anton/data, you can move (mv) the two directories from /home - as in
mv /home/anton/test1 /media/anton/data
and
mv /home/anton/test2 /media/data
By the way, having set this new hard drive at /media/anton/data (I am assuming anton is probably the ID you use for your system), you need to be sure you never name a thumb drive or other external hard drive "data" because the ubuntu method for on-the-fly mounting such USB devices is to put then in /media/[your ID].

What is the better place for ssd mounting instead of /media/{user}/data?

In the past, I've just made up a name and put that at root.  For example.  I had an install of Ubuntu 23.04 (Ubuntu 24.04 is sometimes referred to as Lunar Lobster) no longer being used - I wanted to reference it and, I needed the additional space so I connected it within my desktop tower as an additional drive then modified /etc/fstab to include a line (your line will be different, especially the UUID " UUID=4075bd0d-7195-4173-adeb-5ed493d8bf3e /lunar          ext4    defaults        0       2"  This caused that old drive to be mounted at /lunar.
